# Subversion, connection reset

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am having a great deal of difficulty performing "history" oriented operations in subversion. Installed version is 1.6.x on a LAMP Ubuntu server.  I am using Eclipse as a SVN client but I've also tried it with SVNx, and Tortoise on a Windows instance.

The error I am getting when performing a "compare with latest from repository" is

```
SVN: '0x0000000c: Locate URL in History' operation finished with error: svn: Connection reset
```

I have set the apache TIMEOUT directive at 1200, but the error comes up after about 5 minutes.

Suggestions?  This is killing me...

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? If it is completely up to date, can you supply a trace from the error log?

Comment: Version: 3.7.1.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `http-timeout` in your `~/.subversion/servers` file

see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html

Never changed it in eclipse's subclipse plugin but looks like this setting might be relevant:

`Team > SVN > Configuration Location`

[image]

I've seen this setting misnamed in IntelliJ as a "proxy timeout"